# Javascript .replace method doesn't override CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/does-javascript-have-higher-precedence-than-css/) that **when both CSS and JavaScript target the same element, then the JavaScript changes are applied over CSS.**

However, I've encountered a different behaviour.

Here, we have legal case name: **Johnson V United Care**.

I want to convert all words to uppercase, except the "**V**", which I want to convert to lowercase.

This is what I want: **JOHNSON v UNITED CARE**.

However, in the below code, CSS `uppercase` style seems to override the Javascript code.

I've referred the CSS file in the `<head>` and the JS file just before the closing `</body>` tag.

What I am doing wrong?

Note: After I've posted the question, I've thought that the JS code only changes the innerHTML, and subsequently CSS style is applied to this new HTML. So, this does not seem like a priority issue. But I still can't figure how to apply JS code after CSS in order to get the correct result.

```js
(function() {
  let title = document.querySelector("h1.title>a");

  let a = title.innerHTML;

  let b = a.match(/\b[v]\b/i);

  title.innerHTML = a.replace(b, b.toString().toLowerCase());
})();
```

```css
h1.title>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><a href="https://example.com/case/johnson-v-united-care/">Johnson V United Care</a></h1>
```

Comment: The CSS rule remains in effect. It tells the browser to show the content of the `<a>` as uppercase letters, and it will continue to do that after the content changes.

Comment: Also that linked article is highly misleading, and even then it's talking about something different than what you're trying to do. The "precedence" under discussion relates to how a DOM element's local `style` relates to CSS rules that apply to the element. Usually, local styles override rules from CSS. That has nothing to do with textual content of the element however.

Comment: If you want that "v" to be lower-case, put it in its own `<span>` or something with its own style (either via CSS or the `style` object on the new element).

Comment: Have you checked your regex? Maybe try to run the js code only and see if it works.

Comment: Note that, other problems aside, your code will replace the first `v` in the text and some people have names with that letter in them!

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed JS code works without any problem. The problem arises when the CSS is applied.

Comment: @bonsvr is the name not supposed to change? Like is it always going to be Johnson V United Care and why not change the css? It looks like you're specifically targetting `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it will not be possible to override the CSS property this way, because they are not working on the same property. You're setting the text-transform property in the CSS and in JS code you are just changing the HTML content of the element but not overriding the text-transform property. This way the precedence order will have not effect.
To solve the problem, you should do all text transformations in JS and remove the text-transform property in CSS.

Here is an example:

```js
const title = document.querySelector('h1.title > a');

    const polifyText = (str, char) =>
      str
        .split(' ')
        .map(part => (part.includes(char) ? part.toLowerCase() : part.toUpperCase()))
        .join(' ');

    let newTitle = title.textContent;
    let char = newTitle.match(/\b[v]\b/i);
    
    title.textContent = polifyText(newTitle, char);
```

```css
 h1.title > a {
    /* Comment this out */
          // text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><a href="https://example.com/case/johnson-v-united-care/">Johnson v United Care</a>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I've read here that when both CSS and JavaScript target the same element, then the JavaScript changes are applied over CSS.

That article is very wrong.

Inline style has precedence over rule-sets. It doesn't matter how the two  styles are added to the document. It just *looks* like JS has precedence because JS is used to add inline style.

---

> What I am doing wrong?

CSS changes how the content is presented.

The CSS says it should be presented in uppercase.

It doesn't matter if, in the actual content, a particular character is lower-case because it was written that way in HTML or changed to be that way with JS.

You are changing the content with JS, and then CSS is presenting that content in uppercase.

---

I'd approach the problem by writing extra markup and styling that.

```css
h1.title>a .name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><a href="https://example.com/case/johnson-v-united-care/"><span class="name">Johnson</span> v <span class="name">United Care</a></a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a span around "V" is not an option, because the code is produced dynamically.

Comment: You're already trying to manipulate the DOM using JS to get a different result. Add the spans with JS.

Comment: this may be a good idea. Now I have to figure out how to do that.